# aws pipeline fails after recreating git branch

Tags: aws-pipeline

I have a major upgrade to deploy to our beta site.  To do this, I made a copy of our beta branch, destroyed the beta branch and made a new beta branch from the upgrade branch

```
git checkout beta
git checkout -b beta-2-22-24
git branch -D beta
git checkout upgrade_v2
git checkout -b beta
git push --force origin beta
```

I have a pipeline in AWS that triggers on push to beta which kicked off.  It passed the source stage but fails on the build stage.

```
[Container] 2024/02/22 16:29:57.773232 Running command docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
The push refers to repository [1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/beta-abc-php]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: 1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/beta-abc-php

[Container] 2024/02/22 16:29:57.792631 Command did not exit successfully docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest exit status 1
[Container] 2024/02/22 16:29:57.797306 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/02/22 16:29:57.797320 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest. Reason: exit status 1
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Thanks!